# PHP how to Get data from var_dump stdclass

Tags: php

I use Dropbox API and I need to list all files inside a folder , when I use metaData method using var_dump();
like : var_dump($metaData);

I get these:

```
object(stdClass)#26 (9) { 
    ["hash"]=> string(32) "d36517b72d827dc28b1e0681a23e463a" 
    ["thumb_exists"]=> bool(false) 
    ["bytes"]=> int(0) 
    ["path"]=> string(1) "/" 
    ["is_dir"]=> bool(true) 
    ["size"]=> string(7) "0 bytes" 
    ["root"]=> string(10) "app_folder" 
    ["contents"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> object(stdClass)#27 (12) { 
            ["revision"]=> int(1) 
            ["rev"]=> string(9) "10815f504"  
            ["thumb_exists"]=> bool(false)  
            ["bytes"]=> int(7332680)  
            ["modified"]=> string(31) "Sun, 03 Jun 2012 17:51:47 +0000"  
            ["client_mtime"]=> string(31) "Sun, 03 Jun 2012 17:51:47 +0000"  
            ["path"]=> string(9) "/etmh.pdf"  
            ["is_dir"]=> bool(false)  
            ["icon"]=> string(18) "page_white_acrobat"  
            ["root"]=> string(7) "dropbox"  
            ["mime_type"]=> string(15) "application/pdf"  
            ["size"]=> string(4) "7 MB"  
        }  
    } 
    ["icon"]=> string(6) "folder" 
}
```

How can I deal with these data , for example I need to list all files in this folder 
, now , there is only one file in the example above (["path"]=> string(9) "/etmh.pdf" :: ["mime_type"]=> string(15) "application/pdf" )

I need some thing like foreach to get and deal with all data ..

Thank you ..

Comment: Are you asking how to iterate over `$metaData->contents`?

Comment: Phoenix , Yes exactly , I need to get all files from $metaData->contents .. how can I do that ?

Comment: Chris , sorry, I just copy paste my code inside <code>  I don't know how to format it more than that .. / also thanks to Dev-null-dweller who did that for me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function `get_object_vars()` to extract variables from an object.

Documentation link http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

Comment: Thank you , I really just find this function : // From object to array. function toArray($data) { if (is_object($data)) $data = get_object_vars($data); return is_array($data) ? array_map(FUNCTION, $data) : $data; } and works fine with me – Ahmad just now edit

Answer (score 3):

You can use [get_object_vars()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) and then `dump()` it

```
<?php
    var_dump(get_object_vars($object));
?>
```

`get_object_vars()` returns an array with corresponding `$key=>$value` pairs, which you can then traverse to do something more sensible, e.g. read the info stored in that object. Read the [Manual](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) for a better understanding, it's only a few lines.